# Definition of "dense"

Tags: real-analysis

I've always viewed the definition of "denseness" as "$A$ is dense in $B$ if every open subset of $B$ contains a point of $A$," and this is the definition I used to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But Rudin gives a different definition: Given $X$ a metric space and $E \subset X$, $E$ is dense in $X$ if every point of $X$ is either a limit point of $E$, an element of $E$, or both.

Is there a way to reconcile these two definitions, or is the addition of metric spaces give rise to a completely different definition?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent, and the metric is irrelevant.

Comment: An open set containing a limit point of $E$ will also contain a point of $E$.

Comment: The definition given by Rudin is a bit redundant. If a "limit point of $E$" is considered as a point that is the limit of a sequence of points in $E$, then every point of $E$ is automatically a limit point of $E$.

Comment: @WhatsUp The definition of being a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition) requires that every neighborhood of a point contains a point of the set different from the point itself. So, allowing points of $X$ to be elements of $E$ and not limit points is needed.